# MySql error 1044 (access denied for user) when creating tables on AppHarbor server?

Tags: mysql, database, wcf, appharbor

I have a service that I have put on AppHarbor. I have MySql database and I need to put it also. I changed string connection Alias on AppHarbor website, I am connected on AppHarbor database with user name and password which they gave me - I have a sql script, and I want to create tables but this error is popping out. How to resolve this error, anyone? Thank you :)

Comment: Creating tables should certainly be possible. Can you provide a small example of a query that fails? Are you able to connect to the database and create tables using a database management tool?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have just een your post - I have a script, and I'm able to connect to database. Everytime I run the script it says "Denied for user .......". I granted all for that user and still nothing